# WSO2 identity server with "advanced" service config and grant type password

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2 identity server such that authentication is possible both against the "local" WSO2 provider and Google. 
This works fine in a setup where the grant type is authorization code (the login window allows one to select either wso2 or google to authenticate against)

I can also get a bearer token using grant type password with a user and password of the local WSO2 identity provider.

What I would like to do as well is use grant type password against the Google authenticator service.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how can it be done?

All tips welcome!

Tx

Peter

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. Let's say you can do this. How are you going to get the google account credentials of the user that will be sent in the password grant type? And if we obtain the username, password does Google provide an API to authenticate a user with credentials?

Comment: Yeah. You're right. I need grant type implicit. Thanks for your contribution!